# Maps Javascript API issue: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, connection-timeout

I am trying a simple integration of the Google Map API onto a website. However I am getting this strange error.

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Below is the code:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
>   <head>
>     <meta charset="utf-8">
>     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
>     <<style >
>       *{
>         margin:0;
>         padding:0;
>       }
>       #maps{
>         height: 500px;
>         width: 100%;
>
>       }
>     </style>
>     <title>Test GoogleAPI</title>
>  </head>
>  <body>
>
>     <div class="maps" id="maps"></div>
>
>       <script>
>       function initMap() {
>           var location = {lat: 17.4875, long: 78.3953};
>           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maps'),
>                     {
>                        zoom: 8,
>                        center: location
>                     }
>                    );
>       }
>     </script>
>      <script async defer src="https://maps.gooleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA4T7iyDoU4afVBV-TTTxsEv333****I&callback=initMap"></script>
>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

*I am using Google Chrome last modified 06/23/2020*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two typos.

1. in the [URL for the Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#add_key): `https://maps.gooleapis.com/`, should be: `https://maps.googleapis.com/` (two g's in google). This causes the error in the title of your question: “Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT”
2. a [LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngLiteral) has a `lng` property for longitude, not `long`

```
var location = {lat: 17.4875, long: 78.3953};
```

should be:

```
var location = {lat: 17.4875, lng: 78.3953};
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var location = {
    lat: 17.4875,
    lng: 78.3953
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maps'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: location
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#maps {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
<div class="maps" id="maps"></div>
```